# MongoDB c# driver slow find on index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Got a 50+ million of documents and non-unique index on field "Base.UserID"
Two mongo servers in replicaset and connection string :

```
<add name="MongoConnectionString" connectionString="mongodb://mango1,mango2:27017" />
```

Index insured:

```
var eventCollection = Collection<EventMongo>();
eventCollection.EnsureIndex(IndexKeys.Ascending("Base.UserID"), IndexOptions.SetName("Event.Base.UserID"));
```

Then I do find

```
                var _Set = new SortedSet<Int64>();
                using (var db = new BaseDataAccess())
                {
                    var col = db.Collection<EventMongo>();
                    var counter = 0;
                    var query = Query.And(
                        Query.EQ("Base.UserID", UserID),
                        Query.EQ("Base.Visible", 1)
                    );

                    var _docs = col.Find(query);
                    _docs.SetFields(new[] {"SQLId"});        
                    _docs.SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("SQLId"));
                    _docs.SetLimit(HowMany);

                    int i = 0;                       

                    foreach (var doc in _docs)
                    {   
                        var _EventID = doc.SQLId;
                        _Set.Add(_EventID);
                        if (++counter >= HowMany) break;
                    }
                }

                return _Set;
```

Same documents contains a parrallel MS SQL db, and i mention that the first query for read to MongoDB takes more time (up to 5 seconds) than MS SQL !
(The second hit on the same UserID is faster)

Comment: Could you use the console and confirm the index is there and correct? What does the query plan look like from the console for your query?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are not running the EnsureIndex statement in your production code right before the query, right?

Comment: @AntonioOtero , ofcourse i doing EnsureIndex only once.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I can use `var _stat = _docs.Explain();` and it tells me `{ "cursor" : "BtreeCursor Event.Base.UserID", "isMultiKey" : false, "n" : 12, "nscannedObjects" : 12, "nscanned" : 12, "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 37, "nscannedAllPlans" : 37, "scanAndOrder" : true, "indexOnly" : false, "nYields" : 0, "nChunkSkips" : 0, "millis" : 0, "indexBounds" : { "Base.UserID" : [[2767205, 2767205]] }, "server" : "MANGO:27017" }`

Answer (score 0):

Your index is not being used. If you are querying by "Base.UserID" and "Base.Visible", then you need a compound index with both fields.

Comment: I think you are not right, because target index "Base.UserID" goes first. Moreover, i already tried to leave only "Base.UserID — it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

"scanAndOrder" : true, you want this to be false if possible.

I believe you might want to add your sort to the index.

[MongoBlog on Index Ordering](http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/06/cardinal-ins/)

```
eventCollection.EnsureIndex(IndexKeys.Ascending("Base.UserID"), IndexKeys.Descending("SQLId"), IndexOptions.SetName("Event.Base.UserID"));
```